# model convergence issues using glmer

Tags: r, poisson

I am trying to run a mixed effect poisson model. I am having a problem with model convergence when I enter a specific variable and I am hoping to get thoughts on why that might be. Here is a segment of my data.

```
id   gender race gene   grade  y
1     0      1    -1.5     6   4
1     0      1    -2.1     7   2
1     0      1     1.5     8   6
2     1      2     3.6     6   4
2     1      2     2.1     7   3
2     1      2     1.6     8   1
```

I used the code below and I am getting the error message below.

```
m2<-glmer(y ~ gender + race + gene + grade +
            (1 | id), data=data_long_1, family = "poisson"(link = "log"), control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
                                                                                               
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00392577 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

The problem is the "grade" variable as when I remove the variable, I don't get that error message. Everyone has 3 grandes (6,7,8). I, ideally, want to run grade x gene interactions, but I won't be able to do that if grade isn't in the model.

The estimated coefficients are:

```
Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                    1.683e+00  4.653e-02  36.159  < 2e-16 ***
gender1                       -3.194e-02  3.584e-02  -0.891  0.37288    
race1                          1.329e-01  4.249e-02   3.127  0.00177 ** 
gene                           8.298e-03  2.499e-02   0.332  0.73983    
grade                          2.980e-07  6.552e-03   0.000  0.99996    
gene:grade                     3.346e-07  6.768e-03   0.000  0.99996
```

Can someone provide insight into why this variable might be a problem?

Comment: You've read `?lme4::convergence` (and `?lme4::troubleshooting`), right ... ? (`fortunes::fortune("WTFM")` ....)

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I did read ?lme::convergence, but not the other ones. I will check those out. Thank you! :)

Comment: you might try centering/scaling predictors.  Other than that (and telling us more about your data set: how many obs? how many groups?), try `allFit()` to see if the convergence is actually a problem ...

Comment: Yeah, there's only 1 continuous variable and it is centered. There are about 3,000 observations--no groups. I tried one of the optimizers and I was able to get it to work. The p-values for the main effect of grade and gene x grade are all practically 1 which is a bit concerning to me.

Comment: @BenBolker, I also ran the allFit() function as you suggested, but I'm not completely sure how to interpret it besides the fact that there are issues with model convergence.

Comment: What are the estimated coefficients (`summary(m2)`)?  Do you have complete separation?

Comment: I have added in the coefficients in the comment. I'm not sure what you mean by complete separation, but I just looked it up, and my sense is yes, although it would be great to get your thoughts.

Comment: There's a few other covariates I added FYI, but the issue is with grade, I think.

Comment: complete separation would give rise to *large* coefficients.That's a weird pattern.

Comment: I wasn't sure if grade was coded properly and i tried including it as a factor or numeric to see if that would affect things and it didn't. The only 2 things that fluctuate in the model is grade (6,7,8) and the outcome. All the other variables are constant (i.e., the same across grades and id).

Comment: @BenBolker, would you conclude that the model isn't a good fit?

Comment: can't say with this information.  The parameter estimates approx=0 for `grade` and `gene:grade` certainly look pathological.  What are the results of a `glm()`, i.e. leaving out `(1|id)` ?

Comment: post a link to it if possible, or send it along (no promises) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate your convergence warnings: with the data you sent off-line, on Linux, with a development version of `lme4`, I don't get any convergence warnings — such platform-dependence is not terribly unusual ...

However, I think I can explain your results based on the structure of the data you sent.  Here is a sample for a typical individual, with the values modified for confidentiality:

```
     id gender race  y      gene grade
1  xxxx      1    1  8 -1.543210     6
2  xxxx      1    1  8 -1.543210     7
3  xxxx      1    1  8 -1.543210     8
4  xxxx      1    1  8 -1.543210     9
```

- there are many individuals (between 500 and 1000) in the data set
- the values of `gender`, `race`, `gene`, **and `y`, the response variable do not vary within `id`** (this is important)
- only the value for `grade` varies within `id`, and it is perfectly balanced — each `id` has exactly four observations, for `grade`=6,7,8,9

This means that the average effect of `grade` on `y`, or the interaction of anything with `grade`, is exactly zero!

Since this data set doesn't really have more than one observations' worth of information about each `id` (i.e. the same values are repeated 4 times for each individual, except for `grade`), it might be to better to take only the first observation for each individual and fit

```
glm(y ~ gender + race + gene, data=..., family=poisson)
```

(I usually omit the `(link="log")` because it's the default, but it's fine to include it if it makes the code clearer).

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034261/warning-lme4-model-failed-to-converge-with-maxgrad/) shows that things get more pathological if you try to fit a model with a residual variance term (e.g. LMM/Gaussian response) to such a data set ...

Comment: Thank you @Ben. This is really, really helpful. I appreciate you taking the time to review my data. :)