# Modeling the effect of an exposure that was measured multiple times on an outcome that was measured only once. Is it possible?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I've got repeated measurements data on 173 patients, in whom an exposure was measured 3 times and a continuous outcome once. The dataset also includes a patients' age at each measurement, which is what the data is sorted to.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lme4) 

# Get data
data <- structure(list(id = c("183366", "183366", "183366", "125655", 
"125655", "125655", "558817", "558817", "558817", "822010", "822010", 
"822010", "275957", "275957", "275957", "331423", "331423", "825227", 
"825227", "825227", "154201", "154201", "154201", "382289", "382289", 
"382289", "894212", "894212", "894212", "808173", "808173", "808173", 
"753077", "753077", "753077", "995511", "995511", "995511", "777630", 
"777630", "777630", "982469", "982469", "982469", "024882", "024882", 
"024882", "331676", "331676", "331676", "276304", "276304", "276304", 
"033011", "033011", "033011", "978624", "978624", "978624", "788164", 
"788164", "788164", "648334", "648334", "648334", "328501", "328501", 
"328501", "554368", "554368", "554368", "826851", "826851", "826851", 
"718362", "718362", "718362", "114095", "114095", "114095", "387781", 
"387781", "387781", "754158", "754158", "754158", "156715", "156715", 
"131023", "131023", "131023", "813348", "813348", "813348", "357389", 
"357389", "357389", "427834", "427834", "427834", "837680", "837680", 
"837680", "745209", "745209", "745209", "216738", "216738", "216738", 
"353790", "353790", "353790", "233456", "233456", "233456", "585345", 
"585345", "585345", "076063", "076063", "397722", "397722", "397722", 
"662504", "662504", "662504", "897956", "897956", "897956", "960152", 
"960152", "960152", "079913", "079913", "079913", "001210", "001210", 
"031349", "031349", "031349", "866616", "866616", "866616", "259864", 
"259864", "259864", "039766", "039766", "858950", "858950", "561908", 
"561908", "561908", "962282", "962282", "962282", "859899", "859899", 
"859899", "758119", "758119", "758119", "708152", "708152", "708152", 
"345420", "345420", "345420", "388298", "388298", "388298", "030719", 
"030719", "030719", "611861", "611861", "611861", "543221", "543221", 
"543221", "027992", "027992", "027992", "300323", "300323", "300323", 
"777493", "777493", "777493", "085942", "085942", "085942", "182408", 
"182408", "182408", "658202", "658202", "658202", "359709", "359709", 
"359709", "960515", "960515", "960515", "331885", "331885", "331885", 
"317520", "317520", "659397", "659397", "659397", "685596", "685596", 
"685596", "157722", "157722", "157722", "953448", "953448", "953448", 
"837815", "837815", "837815", "336504", "336504", "336504", "283110", 
"283110", "283110", "166636", "166636", "166636", "389960", "389960", 
"389960", "838273", "838273", "838273", "346868", "346868", "346868", 
"972293", "972293", "972293", "552298", "552298", "552298", "700528", 
"700528", "700528", "450597", "450597", "773134", "773134", "773134", 
"611328", "611328", "565188", "565188", "565188", "624930", "624930", 
"624930", "872179", "872179", "872179", "635885", "635885", "635885", 
"154448", "154448", "154448", "056494", "056494", "056494", "179953", 
"179953", "179953", "971979", "971979", "282267", "282267", "282267", 
"916930", "916930", "916930", "883878", "883878", "883878", "167821", 
"167821", "167821", "310597", "310597", "310597", "175058", "175058", 
"175058", "136376", "136376", "136376", "700210", "700210", "700210", 
"404533", "404533", "404533", "635413", "635413", "635413", "883051", 
"883051", "883051", "955012", "955012", "955012", "335018", "335018", 
"335018", "083779", "083779", "083779", "177594", "177594", "177594", 
"519564", "519564", "519564", "284797", "284797", "284797", "846256", 
"846256", "846256", "546599", "546599", "546599", "795609", "795609", 
"795609", "566766", "566766", "566766", "575600", "575600", "575600", 
"946060", "946060", "946060", "756209", "756209", "108899", "108899", 
"108899", "386197", "386197", "386197", "419538", "419538", "419538", 
"204335", "204335", "204335", "702110", "702110", "639435", "639435", 
"639435", "102333", "102333", "102333", "544834", "544834", "544834", 
"002306", "002306", "002306", "352146", "352146", "352146", "428218", 
"428218", "201949", "201949", "201949", "639782", "639782", "639782", 
"695336", "695336", "695336", "789675", "789675", "789675", "989332", 
"989332", "989332", "303964", "303964", "303964", "382696", "382696", 
"382696", "233023", "233023", "233023", "795953", "795953", "795953", 
"405111", "405111", "405111", "186899", "186899", "186899", "184322", 
"184322", "184322", "869313", "869313", "869313", "775031", "775031", 
"775031", "633353", "633353", "633353", "748704", "748704", "748704", 
"831700", "831700", "831700", "017592", "017592", "017592", "540662", 
"540662", "540662", "158917", "158917", "158917", "456295", "456295", 
"456295", "577879", "577879", "577879", "362191", "362191", "362191"
), age = c(61.2, 66, 70.5, 61, 65.9, 70.5, 57.8, 62.9, 67.2, 
58.1, 62.9, 67.3, 63.1, 66.9, 74, 83.4, 87.8, 71.6, 76.5, 80.9, 
64.4, 68.6, 74.7, 60.6, 64.8, 70.9, 74.7, 79.1, 83.7, 71.7, 76.2, 
80.8, 64.7, 69.2, 74.7, 58.1, 63.1, 68.6, 62.3, 67, 71.6, 60.4, 
65.6, 69.9, 71.1, 76.1, 80.5, 62.4, 67.2, 71.7, 57.6, 62.7, 67, 
57.5, 62.2, 66.7, 60, 65.1, 69.3, 70.4, 75.1, 80.1, 66.1, 71.2, 
75.6, 62.2, 67.4, 71.7, 57, 62.1, 66.5, 62.3, 67.3, 71.7, 60.4, 
65.4, 69.8, 63.1, 68.2, 72.5, 65.9, 71, 75.3, 65.8, 70.7, 75.3, 
62.4, 66.8, 62.7, 67.5, 72.1, 61.1, 65.9, 70.5, 60, 65, 69.3, 
67, 71.9, 76.6, 63.6, 68.6, 73.2, 57.5, 61.8, 67.1, 57.8, 62.6, 
67.1, 63.5, 68, 72.5, 59, 64, 68.4, 60.7, 66.3, 71.2, 66.2, 70.7, 
63.3, 68.4, 72.7, 66.6, 71.6, 76.1, 61.5, 66.4, 70.8, 60.8, 66, 
70.3, 62.8, 66.9, 72.6, 63.6, 68.2, 56.7, 61.6, 66.2, 60.7, 65.7, 
70.1, 63.8, 68.6, 73, 74.4, 78.9, 73.2, 77.7, 56.5, 61.5, 66.3, 
62.5, 67.5, 71.9, 56.8, 62.4, 66.7, 57.1, 61.9, 66.3, 67.1, 71.8, 
76.3, 62.6, 67.3, 71.8, 59.3, 64.1, 68.7, 58.8, 63.6, 68.2, 68.6, 
73.5, 78.4, 67.1, 72.1, 76.9, 60.5, 66.1, 70.3, 63, 67.8, 72.4, 
67.7, 72.8, 77, 65, 70.1, 74.2, 63.9, 68.7, 73.3, 56.6, 61.9, 
66.1, 56.7, 61.6, 66.2, 71.5, 76.1, 81.6, 69.4, 74.6, 78.9, 62.8, 
67.7, 64.2, 69.1, 73.5, 61.3, 66.3, 70.8, 57.7, 62.7, 67.3, 72, 
76.1, 82.4, 62.4, 67, 71.7, 62, 66.5, 71.3, 63.7, 68.9, 73.1, 
59.2, 64, 68.5, 57.2, 62.1, 66.6, 62.6, 67.4, 72.1, 57.1, 62.3, 
66.5, 63, 67.6, 73.1, 69.1, 74, 78.7, 66.7, 71.5, 76.3, 64.3, 
68.7, 68.8, 73.5, 78.3, 79.2, 83.7, 65.8, 70.7, 75.2, 75.6, 80.6, 
85, 72.1, 76.9, 81.4, 63.4, 68.4, 72.9, 68.5, 73.2, 77.7, 57.1, 
61.4, 65.8, 71.8, 76.8, 81.2, 62.8, 67.3, 64.7, 69.6, 74.6, 57.4, 
62.5, 66.8, 65.6, 70.8, 74.9, 62.9, 67.4, 71.9, 69.9, 75.1, 79.3, 
61.2, 66.2, 70.6, 64.9, 69.9, 74.3, 60.3, 65.3, 69.7, 70.2, 75.2, 
79.7, 60.5, 65.4, 70, 57.6, 62.5, 66.8, 56.6, 61.4, 65.8, 72.8, 
77, 83, 67.2, 72.2, 76.9, 61.6, 66.6, 71.3, 78.8, 83.9, 88.3, 
72.3, 77.3, 81.7, 60.2, 65, 69.4, 58.3, 63.1, 67.5, 58.7, 63.3, 
67.9, 66.1, 71, 75.6, 58.1, 62.7, 67.4, 58.7, 63.5, 68, 69.5, 
73.9, 57.2, 62, 66.6, 66.5, 71.3, 75.7, 66.7, 71.5, 76, 59.2, 
64.3, 68.6, 78.8, 83.4, 66, 71.1, 75.4, 73.3, 78.4, 82.7, 64.3, 
68.4, 73.3, 72, 77, 81.4, 74.9, 80, 84.3, 62.3, 66.8, 65.1, 70, 
74.4, 57.6, 62.4, 67, 73.1, 77.9, 82.3, 60.5, 65.2, 69.9, 74.6, 
79.6, 83.9, 61.7, 66.3, 71.2, 66.8, 71.4, 76.2, 64.9, 69.6, 74.2, 
61, 66.2, 70.6, 58.5, 63.7, 67.9, 59.2, 64.2, 69.2, 58.6, 63.6, 
67.8, 57.7, 62.7, 66.9, 59.6, 64.6, 69.3, 63, 68, 72.7, 59.3, 
63.9, 68.5, 65.1, 70.2, 75.1, 71.1, 76, 80.5, 63.5, 68.5, 72.9, 
64.1, 69.1, 73.5, 71.9, 77, 81.2, 73.2, 78.1, 82.7, 76.2, 81.3, 
85.6), exposure = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("Stable", 
"Fall", "Rise"), class = "factor"), exposure_cont = c(0.0335399449035813, 
0.0336473839582941, 0.00894106607372351, -0.0927625976664625, 
0.0378738932759033, -0.0125807284939292, 0.0498492518424775, 
0.0155968229880074, 0.0130773361976369, 0.0842829756643059, 0.018553009202428, 
0.0154050835473187, 0.053011611030479, -0.033095897306821, 0.0137322355064291, 
0.0380478658298393, 0.0488186964383992, 0.101186628497553, -0.0272676371780515, 
0.0463728699635295, 0.0123439057773873, -0.0115171772273637, 
0.0169613977056167, 0.0799289785443586, -0.0194056547803526, 
0.00522118461209803, 0.021175959029858, -0.0281715440916785, 
0.0470788267540119, 0.0869125520523498, 0.00329680744478242, 
0.0248070702697196, -0.00770764750569764, 0.0286345818815331, 
0.0190199102912575, 0.0962861019577437, 0.0133271304252641, -0.00586367379832815, 
0.0335965046757627, 0.0319060652825903, 0.0349452469347643, -0.0788332038332038, 
0.0286354549136951, 0, -0.0226028033045577, 0.021459236473358, 
0.0111743380294617, 0.0555910689009634, 0.00163496703208161, 
0.0563091982302567, -0.0939782285997031, 0.0222019603373604, 
0.0506144305814696, 0.0657600308641975, 0.0161371083538898, 0.00670805057897685, 
0.0785759576082157, -0.0246069670415337, -0.0316506427615132, 
0, 0.0119927107959023, 0.0317329997132953, 0.0646174259177355, 
0.0032146912048161, 0.0197442134748636, 0.137368513839102, -0.0275034691967599, 
0.0128931483638674, -0.117486903777226, 0.0506921110299489, -0.00413544404837611, 
-0.0890543364681296, 0.0357782566714711, 0, -0.0709587444319554, 
0.00201124978318149, -0.0175833065595576, -0.00281681994331656, 
0.00748515404857828, 0.0509253202260228, 0.0509899105273177, 
-0.00628127740803797, 0.0254206814420712, 0.0643464933143069, 
-0.00499435955286637, 0.0514248755956231, 0.04806612793782, 0.00231465834100837, 
-0.0326281154155376, 0.0281686365572952, 0.0252744620543734, 
-0.0493643024703872, 0.021104575138769, 0.00278269813153534, 
0.0746372862884, 0.00804598123155097, -0.0346822053781902, -0.0530546623794212, 
0.00532807212043412, 0.0256761628378561, -0.101423487544484, 
0.0273798439213768, 0.0307066280187586, -0.0598110533774209, 
0.0434593537969035, 0, -0.0675950772647358, 0.0485683258720801, 
-0.0344486758891769, 0.0822357311719014, -0.00747143365612381, 
0.0219779448340046, 0.125488021988319, 0.0155979757863045, 0.0195571856928679, 
0.100843622977222, -0.0297988931645432, 0.0820951915922619, 0.0170045857678251, 
0.0323520059958438, 0.0139610886017889, 0.00929424787205619, 
0.0491145098846893, -0.0668138392077627, 0.0234616883422762, 
-0.00684065625351163, -0.0763208955223881, -0.0106223644030827, 
0.075953470766772, 0.0803392411488516, 0.0177542836310609, 0.0258987449478834, 
0.0246640556418394, 0.0301456487437796, 0.00476659663043053, 
0.0206147634398098, 0.00781575991012678, -0.0286181040359166, 
0.0654237692927725, -0.0543407562824853, -0.111075098434649, 
0.0332580606976681, 0.00307611327508159, 0.0887271541721804, 
-0.0119636423190305, 0.0424037710922957, 0.101633440174703, -0.0327358822514041, 
0.067277583348683, -0.00642593244194229, 0.104744433198381, 0.0240707789640174, 
-0.0270355292376018, -0.032669946332737, 0.0542071197411003, 
0.0151770132136624, -0.0717679632027866, 0.0103602745720954, 
0.0280740185622874, -0.0408351500922355, 0.0224102668984559, 
0.0182671428988201, -0.0194152823920266, 0.0101180088091083, 
0.050046217588401, 0.100033937055692, -0.0237737829360866, 0.0294096457789917, 
0.0664839434608195, -0.0436495817288541, 0.0630937985835205, 
0.0278483039410783, -0.0100547816990585, 0.0736094316807739, 
-0.0961071065040819, 0.0205670364322315, 0.00521329550928652, 
-0.087818072530555, 0.0342354117414262, 0.0202373256995106, -0.0832719524385753, 
0.0144431527000095, -0.0115799207397622, -0.0943359677669301, 
0.0576003154021377, -0.00605741483962984, 0.100298630419112, 
0.0262371298587278, 0.00335510361552028, 0.00608658701194821, 
0.00478336789261159, 0.0309935609463911, -0.101653976899986, 
-0.010426925876761, 0.0241630242173656, -0.0216604892512973, 
0.029107871417063, -0.00888830304996755, 0.0748974709501025, 
0.0154986055016144, -0.0136183143490986, -0.0502907346212506, 
0.0141446108699113, -0.00982634959295641, -0.00683911920008988, 
0.0183026042357519, -0.0220471140889554, 0.0318914064400247, 
0.00640280244951384, 0.0821635848292617, 0.0240896391797453, 
0.0218798331409153, 0.135105848208358, -0.0219569817491043, 0.0425797475347767, 
0.058774360808153, 0.00647376816731655, 0.0086081540017016, -0.0185142944038929, 
0.0637117793215354, 0.00717981361450151, -0.0879823673941321, 
0.0106254545454545, 0.035359527406762, 0.146839537306069, -0.0155889884763124, 
0.0439793649181031, -0.00574075820445115, 0.0198286176030268, 
-0.00180052499907571, -0.0863500694464966, 0.00473578777447148, 
0.0267679892052913, -0.0287693567951606, 0.0398722777140986, 
-0.0172776904258262, 0.113150557620818, -0.00741484349148283, 
0.0262930569053018, -0.0674141749723145, 0.0278124916014943, 
0.0407922045287444, 0.00856891495601173, -0.0105739306651227, 
0.049727349594428, 0.0585685160580932, -0.024208782104391, 0.0468900442903909, 
0, 0.0207853179684166, 0.0425658903500667, 0.00622284692052134, 
0.0164673155908622, -0.0377431605053088, 0.0109315375982043, 
0.0488439611486486, 0.0800041741487939, -0.0259623586276616, 
0.0727701149425287, 0.0114178535841979, -0.0294050558179476, 
0.0428125595229374, 0.0129546542765433, 0.0182397003745318, 0.141686466566455, 
-0.0105288191291564, 0.0163114050154586, -0.0801267988767989, 
0.0342206788374444, -0.0272157824486834, 0.0402250325801656, 
0.00404249275062902, -0.00142974575773589, 0.041719017704169, 
-0.00401775401775402, -0.00523685946147449, 0.0631537996023169, 
0.00875437419107425, 0.0396706631991166, 0.127966071828381, -0.00785191616023813, 
0.0405382907880133, 0.020890926769747, -0.0237269968540327, -0.0217624452587363, 
0.0412047272032534, 0.0100038148898084, 0, 0.0369262175561388, 
0.00806818583445253, 0.0176651955746327, -0.0197606005274904, 
0.0188007322679044, 0.0516502630239267, 0, 0.0479324990157598, 
0.0539519800185312, -0.00444101102371232, -0.0326310303752233, 
0.0362027951234017, -0.0278570611409177, 0.0409693286750661, 
0.0367555095527666, 0.0028828281313512, 0.0096566949118934, -0.0419765551888883, 
0.0506617349592556, 0.0224602963597988, -0.116366127182363, 0.0401820093143786, 
-0.00597555788233754, -0.0501992853216053, 0.0438391355101741, 
-0.0130121125757036, 0.0369032583985855, 0.0135605630897747, 
0.00159797873736711, -0.0183904052686434, -0.0181167507402943, 
0.0319434635389165, -0.0885937784245952, -0.00947606013828173, 
0.0294655033887754, -0.0628044936092165, -0.00143782513448241, 
0.0133106714150067, 0.0346164781702155, -0.00291861440728755, 
0.0360181618228708, 0.0394076711441981, -0.0252873592332359, 
0.0433345417394457, 0.0255707474849306, -0.00618412698412698, 
0.032047626150512, 0.0470326911004877, 0.00678745644599303, -0.00184048616045109, 
0.124406069585654, 0.0044223357924063, 0.0279167790666307, 0.0055708075955159, 
-0.00146109350998464, 0.0220272630856572, 0.0429589640450231, 
0.0249213449073197, 0.0117782415213245, -0.115534082949864, 0.0372875299882599, 
-0.0367269984917044, 0.0170232102908277, -0.00996183734611156, 
0.0133016497323282, 0.0045248392303871, 0.0531634387365055, 0.0518158604057313, 
0.0192042904040985, 0.0539098316051555, 0.13563300708204, 0.0386318865105702, 
-0.0147744893143666, 0.0237560975609756, 0.00935067927362097, 
0.0217050454259757, 0.0348998867724413, 0.00676962426500229, 
-0.0261262356761706, 0.04969539883874, -0.0267017635282562, -0.00558016958215568, 
0.0158031368307193, 0.0654210682763982, -0.0260213116756229, 
-0.00185801272757794, 0.0363150265166806, -0.105492741188763, 
0.00336449889462049, 0.0411323480786095, 0.012663165011181, 0.0527496959562177, 
-0.0317222511724857, 0.0336839955733558, 0.00412935829602496, 
-0.0306349250726907, -0.0210992541441988, 0.0366661647342268, 
0.0815871543081007, 0.025598768142381, -0.00926912828321279, 
-0.0240898298377523, 0.0314702015036918, 0.0367002754534588, 
-0.0246482437493673, 0.00480802983764809, 0.00237076542782499, 
-0.067251923456303, 0.02026320169286, 0.00567703042515279, -0.00832421714754547, 
0.0297645726206677, 0.0152769935378631, 0.00470177064627624, 
0.0286767303726027, 0.0222961527309353, 0.00623033032264668, 
0.0193161986355704, 0.0410610482137086, -0.0748003276674176, 
0.0254207207583413, 0.0223846295274867, 0.0644558823529412, -0.0207279275346502, 
0.0535499604148136, 0.0831928753644315, 0.0210670511896179, 0.00986002942486536, 
-0.0512783514803607, 0.00846314794347243, 0.0353722281542549, 
0.00614805837499369, 0.0203166006765879, 0.0301248734570406, 
-0.115659721898837, 0.0705206590294761, 0.00913434162331866, 
0.0308696754563894, 0.00303391505868476, 0.0103500026157012, 
-0.079136840526329, 0.04746958827199, -0.00971051534431816, 0.0608587709944015, 
0.00762858950982788, 0.0105960388407455, -0.0260427807486631, 
0.00376507576538501, 0.0451215595196917, 0.0270573593795142, 
0.0395720476706392, 0.017338600298386, 0.0146390829781833, -0.00977771403986806, 
0.0685430824998707, 0.0551676552974131, -0.0179635451542975, 
0.0165413704089489, 0.0200109574030955, -0.00690509814597406, 
0.061204398673416, 0.0875164729843057, -0.0297294692198946, 0.0891664262411505
), outcome_cont = c(2.26995859016695, 2.26995859016695, 2.26995859016695, 
0, 0, 0, 5.01476010867321, 5.01476010867321, 5.01476010867321, 
4.13678125241936, 4.13678125241936, 4.13678125241936, 0, 0, 0, 
2.58309148169673, 2.58309148169673, 5.31143100569342, 5.31143100569342, 
5.31143100569342, 0, 0, 0, 4.18000224560406, 4.18000224560406, 
4.18000224560406, 6.65664040221807, 6.65664040221807, 6.65664040221807, 
3.42178401527054, 3.42178401527054, 3.42178401527054, 0, 0, 0, 
3.88158441628758, 3.88158441628758, 3.88158441628758, 2.70370745166807, 
2.70370745166807, 2.70370745166807, 0, 0, 0, 3.91653282090597, 
3.91653282090597, 3.91653282090597, 3.37789463609232, 3.37789463609232, 
3.37789463609232, 0, 0, 0, 3.63363097988346, 3.63363097988346, 
3.63363097988346, 4.46898384352978, 4.46898384352978, 4.46898384352978, 
5.76680735081098, 5.76680735081098, 5.76680735081098, 5.20172386363676, 
5.20172386363676, 5.20172386363676, 0, 0, 0, 5.57270521104926, 
5.57270521104926, 5.57270521104926, 3.43945609377925, 3.43945609377925, 
3.43945609377925, 3.95293459593456, 3.95293459593456, 3.95293459593456, 
6.39433128236735, 6.39433128236735, 6.39433128236735, 4.93868806278287, 
4.93868806278287, 4.93868806278287, 1.64113035916659, 1.64113035916659, 
1.64113035916659, 2.9394264373429, 2.9394264373429, 1.83800672039337, 
1.83800672039337, 1.83800672039337, 4.07312092577047, 4.07312092577047, 
4.07312092577047, 3.63727032038071, 3.63727032038071, 3.63727032038071, 
3.18705486587836, 3.18705486587836, 3.18705486587836, 3.94449019556565, 
3.94449019556565, 3.94449019556565, 4.97622326732274, 4.97622326732274, 
4.97622326732274, 4.44550600135535, 4.44550600135535, 4.44550600135535, 
2.95808232610209, 2.95808232610209, 2.95808232610209, 3.9814184625333, 
3.9814184625333, 3.9814184625333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.30325373733203, 
3.30325373733203, 3.30325373733203, 3.19716177196145, 3.19716177196145, 
3.19716177196145, 1.88479433519524, 1.88479433519524, 1.88479433519524, 
3.86392460193711, 3.86392460193711, 3.86392460193711, 4.50987000613377, 
4.50987000613377, 4.50987000613377, 0, 0, 2.67779715793119, 2.67779715793119, 
2.67779715793119, 0, 0, 0, 5.66591444621231, 5.66591444621231, 
5.66591444621231, 4.13765944690804, 4.13765944690804, 5.17761758131025, 
5.17761758131025, 0, 0, 0, 4.07264413524276, 4.07264413524276, 
4.07264413524276, 0, 0, 0, 2.33029753156058, 2.33029753156058, 
2.33029753156058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.05809655775054, 3.05809655775054, 
3.05809655775054, 0, 0, 0, 2.81798026047441, 2.81798026047441, 
2.81798026047441, 4.41483258639906, 4.41483258639906, 4.41483258639906, 
5.77193321387151, 5.77193321387151, 5.77193321387151, 4.84435242711978, 
4.84435242711978, 4.84435242711978, 4.2314217444315, 4.2314217444315, 
4.2314217444315, 0, 0, 0, 2.11745960886736, 2.11745960886736, 
2.11745960886736, 0.77794778225241, 0.77794778225241, 0.77794778225241, 
0, 0, 0, 3.94818134198142, 3.94818134198142, 3.94818134198142, 
3.30428258181007, 3.30428258181007, 3.30428258181007, 5.51631570392156, 
5.51631570392156, 3.8300534425609, 3.8300534425609, 3.8300534425609, 
5.5100156701775, 5.5100156701775, 5.5100156701775, 6.11869173492565, 
6.11869173492565, 6.11869173492565, 6.37772305026336, 6.37772305026336, 
6.37772305026336, 3.18705486587836, 3.18705486587836, 3.18705486587836, 
0, 0, 0, 4.93869522674812, 4.93869522674812, 4.93869522674812, 
4.90497843823771, 4.90497843823771, 4.90497843823771, 4.68155698820653, 
4.68155698820653, 4.68155698820653, 6.21041933780074, 6.21041933780074, 
6.21041933780074, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.6116127194652, 2.6116127194652, 
2.6116127194652, 3.72550063756958, 3.72550063756958, 3.72550063756958, 
4.07870625210864, 4.07870625210864, 4.61388212659011, 4.61388212659011, 
4.61388212659011, 5.30014569413807, 5.30014569413807, 4.75514071256439, 
4.75514071256439, 4.75514071256439, 4.13888762497277, 4.13888762497277, 
4.13888762497277, 5.38360934955999, 5.38360934955999, 5.38360934955999, 
5.34973265349419, 5.34973265349419, 5.34973265349419, 6.16658314140707, 
6.16658314140707, 6.16658314140707, 1.71289662080233, 1.71289662080233, 
1.71289662080233, 5.03420206991815, 5.03420206991815, 5.03420206991815, 
5.1235055410031, 5.1235055410031, 5.00361067915929, 5.00361067915929, 
5.00361067915929, 3.03864807453082, 3.03864807453082, 3.03864807453082, 
3.40552135314221, 3.40552135314221, 3.40552135314221, 2.28115714558043, 
2.28115714558043, 2.28115714558043, 6.44699361094314, 6.44699361094314, 
6.44699361094314, 5.05327962714855, 5.05327962714855, 5.05327962714855, 
4.77912349311153, 4.77912349311153, 4.77912349311153, 3.74121095937402, 
3.74121095937402, 3.74121095937402, 0, 0, 0, 3.96442568422119, 
3.96442568422119, 3.96442568422119, 3.3599933697381, 3.3599933697381, 
3.3599933697381, 4.03609732053007, 4.03609732053007, 4.03609732053007, 
3.93810002513826, 3.93810002513826, 3.93810002513826, 6.12924409104655, 
6.12924409104655, 6.12924409104655, 4.89704097351133, 4.89704097351133, 
4.89704097351133, 2.93656596288477, 2.93656596288477, 2.93656596288477, 
5.79118571930012, 5.79118571930012, 5.79118571930012, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.51116334316576, 1.51116334316576, 1.51116334316576, 
5.24177876058749, 5.24177876058749, 5.24177876058749, 1.96850998097255, 
1.96850998097255, 1.96850998097255, 3.10090277115953, 3.10090277115953, 
3.10090277115953, 5.3543999240843, 5.3543999240843, 4.93810761108917, 
4.93810761108917, 4.93810761108917, 4.72571385203991, 4.72571385203991, 
4.72571385203991, 5.23406147213444, 5.23406147213444, 5.23406147213444, 
5.59888851681002, 5.59888851681002, 5.59888851681002, 3.8662094068886, 
3.8662094068886, 3.87593976525506, 3.87593976525506, 3.87593976525506, 
4.18833569064234, 4.18833569064234, 4.18833569064234, 0, 0, 0, 
5.61607267200596, 5.61607267200596, 5.61607267200596, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.01167475367092, 5.01167475367092, 5.01167475367092, 
5.02129164628476, 5.02129164628476, 5.02129164628476, 6.6585385062256, 
6.6585385062256, 6.6585385062256, 5.93292665281047, 5.93292665281047, 
5.93292665281047, 1.79342474854712, 1.79342474854712, 1.79342474854712, 
0, 0, 0, 5.72676956863554, 5.72676956863554, 5.72676956863554, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.16069571280174, 3.16069571280174, 3.16069571280174, 
5.63930795147072, 5.63930795147072, 5.63930795147072, 0, 0, 0, 
6.86898014654302, 6.86898014654302, 6.86898014654302, 4.85529056834648, 
4.85529056834648, 4.85529056834648, 5.28333569972487, 5.28333569972487, 
5.28333569972487, 2.48315511674919, 2.48315511674919, 2.48315511674919, 
4.06140806197584, 4.06140806197584, 4.06140806197584, 4.88531391640157, 
4.88531391640157, 4.88531391640157, 3.59755880553621, 3.59755880553621, 
3.59755880553621, 4.78026569769031, 4.78026569769031, 4.78026569769031, 
3.34656518600909, 3.34656518600909, 3.34656518600909, 5.12578969272635, 
5.12578969272635, 5.12578969272635), outcome_dich = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -452L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've modelled the relationship between the exposure and the outcome using `lmer::lme4`, but that gives me two warnings and also results in *very* small estimates:

```
model <- lmer(formula=icac_perc ~ 1 + exposure + (1|id), 
              data=data, 
              REML=TRUE)
summary(model)

Warning messages:
1: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$pp), lower = rho$lower,  :
  convergence code -4 from nloptwrap: NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED: Roundoff errors led to a breakdown of the optimization algorithm. In this case, the returned minimum may still be useful. (e.g. this error occurs in NEWUOA if one tries to achieve a tolerance too close to machine precision.)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00459166 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

Any help on why this occurs? Is this due to the fact that the outcome is only measured once?

NB. In the past I've tried to model this relationship using GEE, but that also results in very small estimates (probably due to the same problem?):

```
model <- geeglm(formula=(log(outcome_cont+1))~exposure, data=data, id=id, family=gaussian("identity"), corstr="ar1", control=geese.control(maxit=as.integer(100000)))
summary(model)
```

Spaghetti plot:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=outcome_cont, y=exposure_cont, group=id, color=factor(id))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(group=1), method="lm", formula=y~x, se=FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034261/warning-lme4-model-failed-to-converge-with-maxgrad/53053309#53053309

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760090/model-convergence-issues-using-glmer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the reply and those previous solutions. If I understand correctly, because the response variable does not vary within individuals, adding a random effect per individual explains all variation in the data, leaving nothing for other fixed effects or as residual? The following two questions arise for me: (1) Would the solution be to run a glm without random effects? Wouldn't it be problematic that that doesn't take the repeated measurements of `exposure` into account? (2) Values for `exposure` are not balanced, so the average effect should not be 0?

Comment: I've added some more data on continuous versions of both the exposure and the outcome, and also a spaghetti plot of both those variables.